# How to chain HTTP request requests in Jmeter Simple Controller?

Tags: jmeter

I have multiple Simple Controllers under Thread group. All controllers have 1 HTTP request. Only one controller have 3 requests. How can I chain 3 requests in one simple controller to run sequentially.
[Test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDrRO.png)

The screenshot above is my test plan. In v4/bootstrap call I have 3 HTTP requests. Result of these 3 requests is token which I extract from get_v4/restart and then this token used for all other requests. For correct token generation 3 requests from v4/bootstrap call should run sequently. On summary report shown that amount of run 3 requests is different.

Answer (score 0):

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down. The same applies to [Simple Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller).

[image]

**So you don't need to do literally anything, each thread will execute samplers sequentially as they appear in the Test Plan.**

---

If you have more than 1 virtual user in the Thread Group you might be confused by the "wrong" order of sample results:

[image]

However each user is still executing samplers upside down, you can check it by adding [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function to show the current virtual user's number and [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) calling [vars.getIteration() method](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

You will see that each user executes samplers sequentially and starts over when the last sampler ends and there are iterations still:

[image]

Comment: I update the question and add screenshot. Can you please take a look. Thank you!